# What is the fastest way to sort array containing numbers of double type in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting

What is the fastest way to sort array containing numbers of double type in C++ ? I have two types of arrays first of length 20 and second of length 5000, does length of arrays makes difference for which algorithms is fastest ? Arrays of length 5000 contain on average 28 different values.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38381/STL-Sort-Comparison-Function

Comment: it depends upon many cases - like order of elements, size

Comment: @Kerrek SB, no I don't it's only remark

Comment: At these lengths it doesn't make a difference, all usual algorithms are fast enough.

Comment: Just use `std::sort`... Size matters, the distribution of the numbers matters, but you won't notice it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question: If your array have only a small set of unique values (like 28 as you say) you may want to consider some sort of counting sort (flavors: radix, pigeonhole, bucket). If you know hard limits and ranges of your array content you may be able to do something good.

But as previously said, for such small array you are probably good with std::sort, unless you have a lot of 5000-element arrays to sort.

For the second question: Length matter (see sky's answer). O(n log n) is the best any normal sort can do. O(n^2) is normally the worst case. O(n^2) means that in worst case your 20 element array would need time corresponding to 20^2 (=400) operations, and your 5000 array time corresponding to 5000^2 (=25million) operations. As you can see larger array means much more time in this case. For your case and a O(n log n) algorithm the 5000 array would need time corresponding to 5000 log 5000 (=18500) operations.

What an operation is and how long it takes depend on the particular implementation, and is in general irrelevant for comparison (and thus ignored with Ordo notation). A slow implementation of a O(n log n) algorithm will still be faster than a fast implementation of a O(n^2) algorithm when the array size is large enough. But for a small array like 20 elements a good low overhead implementation matter most. 400 fast operations will be faster than 26 slow operations. Same comparison for 5000 array give that 25million fast operations  would still not be faster than 18500 slow operations.

Another factor is the content of the array. Some algorithms, like insertion sort, are particularly fast (approaching O(n)) on arrays that are in almost correct order, while poor O(n^2) on random input.

By utilizing predefined (known) limitations/ranges on array content (thus not a classified as a normal sort) counting sort can approach O(n), that is, the time is directly proportional to the number of elements. See wikipedia.

Happy research!

Comment: What do you mean by "normal sort"? You mean that the best a pairwise-comparison-based sort can do is O(n log₂ n) in its worst case, yes?

Answer (score 1):

I makes a difference, but your best bet is to use std::sort . It internally switches the sort algorithm considered best depending on the input size.

See wikipedia references:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_%28C++%29
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort

Comment: But `std::sort` is a comaparison sort. It doesn't take any advantage of the fact that you're sorting numbers.

Comment: What advantage can you have from sorting numbers compared to any other data type that defines some comparison predicate?

Comment: @BernhardKausler — Many advantages! For example, integers can be bucket-sorted or radix-sorted. This approach can *way* faster than a pairwise-comparison-based sort. And floating-point numbers can always be converted to integers for the purpose of broad-phase bucket sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to search for sorting algorithms like Quicksort, merge sort, insert sort, or bubble sort.

Sorting depends heavily on the number of items to be sorted, as can be seen from the notation for sorting algorithms, 'big O notation'. Average number of different values and data type often doesn't make a difference enough in runtime to matter. An algorithm of `O(n^2)`(bubble sort) has a complexity of the square of the number of elements you have, telling you that it time increases roughly quadratically in regards to number of items to sort. Quicksort has `O(n log n)` complexity, making it one of the fastest sort methods around.

Bubblesort is the easiest to implement and the slowest in runtime.

Edit: As the comments say, short arrays of only 5000 values don't really have a big difference no matter what algorithm you use, provided it's not something like Bogosort.

Comment: "Sorting depends heavily on the number of items to be sorted, as can be seen from the notation for sorting algorithms, 'big O notation'." OP asked if the type of optimal algorithm may change with the change in size not if sorting depends on size what is obvious

Comment: I see I missed that, but the explanation of big O notation might have answered it in a roundabout way... Optimal algorithms are ones with the lowest complexity, most probably. Therefore quicksort and mergesort. There's still the fact that at the low numbers of values to be sorted that all algorithms yield similar runtimes.